# Big list of repositories of mathematical preprints and postprints

Tags: big-list, journals

I'm looking for a extensive list of online repositories of mathematical preprints and postprints. I'm interested in every type of repository, including small informal and semi-formal collections, like for example the webpage of Ranicki, collecting various [notes on surgery theory](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/surgery/notes.htm), and the Clay Foundation's online collections, like the one with the [collected works of James Arthur](http://www.claymath.org/publications/collected-works-james-g-arthur). Surely there are many other similar sites out there.

[Here is a related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42286/link-repository-of-international-dissertations), which asks specifically about repositories for theses.

Comment: http://www.library.illinois.edu/mtx/refer-research/preprints.html

Comment: Langlands' collected works in the institute's website - http://publications.ias.edu/rpl

Comment: Directory of Open Access Repositories: http://www.opendoar.org/find.php

Comment: I also have some old topology notes collected on my web site, though I agree it would be nice to have sort of a meta-page linking to all such sites. Here's my site: http://faculty.tcu.edu/gfriedman/notes/

Answer (score 15):

For completeness, I guess it's worth mentioning the obvious repository, the [arxiv](http://arxiv.org), specifically the [mathematics section](http://arxiv.org/archive/math).

Answer (score 9):

- [Linear algebraic groups and related structures](http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/LAG/), papers related to linear groups from 1998 to present.
- [K-theory preprint archives](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/) for K-theory related papers between 1994 and 2012 (with a recent addition on the end of the Journal of K-theory)
- [Hopf topology archive](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/), algebraic topology related papers until 2010

Answer (score 9):

The french repository HAL might be of interest too:
[HAL](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/search/index/q/*/domain_t/math/)

Answer (score 6):

- Max Planck Institute for Mathematics [preprint series](https://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/node/263)
- Max Planck Institute for Mathematics in the Sciences [preprint series](http://www.mis.mpg.de/publications/preprints/)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to arXiv as already mentioned, see too this **[directory of mathematics preprint servers](http://www.mathontheweb.org/mathweb/mi-preprints.html)**:

> It makes available the current homepage URLs and email contacts of
>   mathematical preprint and e-print servers throughout the world. It is
>   a tool to help find these servers in order to browse the articles
>   posted on them or to post an article to the server itself. The servers
>   are divided into three categories: umbrella servers which cover all
>   areas of mathematics such as the Mathematics ArXiv and the
>   MPRESS/MathNet.preprints server, special subject servers and servers
>   administered by mathematics departments and institutes. There is an
>   additional link to retired preprint services.

Insofar as mathematics and cryptography intersect, I would suggest the **[IACR cryptography eprint service](http://eprint.iacr.org/)**.

Regarding viXra, **[we discussed it over on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401974/submit-papers-arxiv-or-vixra)** awhile ago. It is distinct from the **[snarXiv](http://snarxiv.org/)**.

Comment: I guess this kind of directory is precisely what I was looking for. But unfortunately all the links are dead!

Answer (score 5):

There is [viXra.org](http://vixra.org/).

I don't really know what the incentive is to post things there rather than arXiv, and the quality is usually lower, but I have found a couple papers which I thought were interesting.

Comment: The incentive seems to be that if you are rejected from the arXiv then it gives you a place to put things. (Note that I am not making **any** comment about the relative standards of the two)

Comment: Yes, arXiv math will reject papers "that are not even plausibly interesting to a serious reader". viXra doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: Another major reason for researchers to post things on viXra instead of on arXiv is that they may lack an academic affiliation.

Comment: Just so nobody misunderstands @DanielMoskovich's comment, I would point out that arXiv does not require contributors to have an academic affiliation. However, authors without such affiliation might be required to obtain endorsement from an established contributor.

Answer (score 4):

There is a fairly large server for preprints in mathematical physics at U of Texas

[Mathematical Physics Preprint Archive mp_arc](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/)

Answer (score 4):

There are links [here](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~alf/) to many papers by the late Alf van der Poorten.

The collected papers of Paul Erdos are available [here](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/).

Comment: The link to Alf's papers is defunct. I believe there is still a site hosting all those papers, but I don't have the URL.

Answer (score 4):

1. The Kurt Mahler archive: http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/mahler/
2. A repository of e-prints about optimization and related topics: http://www.optimization-online.org/

Answer (score 2):

- Repository of the University of Jyväskylä (not limited to mathematics), [JYX](https://jyx.jyu.fi/).
- Department of Mathematics and Statistics (University of Jyväskylä): [reports](https://www.jyu.fi/maths/julkaisut/reports) and [preprints](https://www.jyu.fi/maths/julkaisut/preprints).

Answer (score 2):

- The preprint server of the research group in Calculus of Variations and Geometric Measure Theory at Pisa: http://cvgmt.sns.it/

(A similar project for Complex Geometry and Differential Geometry is at http://gecogedi.dimai.unifi.it/, but preprint functionality is not (yet) available.)

Answer (score 2):

- http://dl.acm.org/  "Full text of every article ever published by ACM [Association for Computing Machinery]".
- http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/  Other papers in (theoretical) computer science.

Unfortunately many papers on both sites are paywalled. But the full text of many of these can be found via Google.

Comment: These are not preprint servers. They are a combination of (1) the papers published by those particular publishers, in their conferences and journals, and (2) in the ACM case at least, bibliographic data but not the papers themselves for some other papers.

Comment: @DavidEppstein, the question says "preprints and postprints", so it is not clear to me whether the asker is interested in repositories such as these or not.

Comment: It also says "interested in every type of repository", so maybe a clarification of the question would be helpful....

Answer (score 1):

[Groups, Representations and Cohomology Preprint Archive](http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/mth192/pages/html/archive.html) maintained by Dave Benson.

Answer (score 1):

Real Algebraic and Analytic Geometry preprint server,

http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/raag/

Comment: Is that preprint server still alive?

Answer (score 0):

No one has mentioned the AMS repository at BROWN
AND THE MAA at UTexas?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit what you refer to, possibly adding a link. I do not know what you mean, even after searching a bit.

Comment: Presumably he means MathSciNet. Which is a very valuable bibliographic database, but not a preprint server.